# Device enrollment screen using Azure AD login with Office 365 SharePoint Resource - iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, office365, azure-active-directory, iosdeployment

We are using Azure AD app to allow our iOS app authentication. When we use SharePoint online url `https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/` as resource id to get OAuth token during login process, we are redirected to below (device must be managed) screen instead of User Consent page/ App. It works fine with other API resource id. Any help on this will greatly help to resolve. We see this issue only with iOS and Android apps.

authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(`https://microsoft.sharepoint.com`, Constants.ADALClientID, _returnUri,   new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController));

[image]

Comment: Are you using Microsoft's ADALios library?  Do you have the Microsoft Authenticator app installed on the device?  Is the device managed? If the device is not managed and you don't want it to be managed then you need to change the security profile for your sharepoint instance so that device management is not required.

Comment: You need to look at the conditional access profile in Azure AD for your sharepoint

Comment: Yes, The device is registered. I get this screen only for Office 365 Resource Id url. How to check "Conditional Access Profile" on Azure AD?

Comment: What about my other questions? Also, have you set the `credentialsType` on your `ADAuthenticationContext` to `AD_CREDENTIALS_AUTO`?  Information on conditional access is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-azure-portal-get-started), but if you shouldn't need to change it if you set up ADALios correctly and have the Authenticator app on a managed device